# How to notify when a span is deleted by using backspace?

Tags: android, android-edittext, spannablestring

I have added various spans dynamically in the SpannableStringBuilder and I have added that ssb in the edittext.

```
SpannableStringBuilder ssb=new SpannableStringBuilder(edittext.getText());
ssb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(bmp),start,end,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
edittext.setText(ssb);
```

Then I added KeyListener on the edittext.
My question is How to notify the application when and span is deleted by using backspace.Please note that simple text is also written in the edit text along with the spans and i only want to notify when the span is deleted and not the normal text.

Comment: use a SpanWatcher class

Answer (score 0):

Use `EditText` `addTextChangedLister`

Comment: addTextChangedLister only not help it will be called for every text entered my keyboard

Comment: check for edittext.getText().toString().length() in your textchangedlistener. If it's less than previous length, user should have pressed backspace.